# SQL How to create a list from Dual inside a WITH

Tags: sql, with-statement, dual-table

I don't want to create tmp tables. How to make this work?

```
with a as (
340401182,
340401183
)
select * from a
```

Comment: Which database are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want two rows and one column do this

```
with a as 
(
   Select 340401182 as val from dual
   UNION ALL
   Select 340401183 as val from dual
)
select * from a
```

Comment: You forgot the `FROM DUAL` in each part of the `UNION ALL`

Comment: Matthew McPeak --I didn't read the question the same way you did.  I didn't take "dual" to be a source object and at any rate, when specifying constants, the from clause doesn't add anything-- at least not in Transact-SQL

Comment: hmmm.  I read "from dual" and assumed Oracle.  Sorry, I may have jumped the gun.

Comment: In some SQL dialects specifying a source object that doesn't exist would actually cause an error, as in PostGreSQL

Comment: I read dual to be shorthand for dual values, that was intended to fit the question into the subject line

Comment: `DUAL` is a table in Oracle that exists specifically for selecting values (constants or expressions) that do not exist in database tables.  It is needed because, in Oracle SQL, the `FROM` clause is required.  His mention of "dual" made me assume Oracle.  I apologize for assuming too quickly.

Comment: OOOOOOOOOOoooooh.   You may well be right.  I don't think he said what dialect he's using.  I work in MS and PostgreSQL and neither of those requires a source object for constants.

Answer (score 1):

Very close....

```
with a as (
SELECT 
    340401182 AS Col1,
    340401183 as Col2
)
select * from a
```